# UGLY BORDER bug, position:relative > position:absolute > border-radius:50% , see fiddle

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

https://jsfiddle.net/0h3rqqru/

```
<div style="position:relative; width:500px; height:500px; background:blue; border-radius:50%;">
     <span style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:white; border-radius:50%;"></span>
</div>
```

My problem is that an odd border is showing up when having a position:absolute inside of a position:relative with border-radius:50%.

Been searching for hours for a solution for this but been unable to find an answer.

Ive been working for Days building something slightly more advanced, a "pie chart". Everything works besides this border issue. Without a solution to the border problem, i might aswell throw it all in the trash ;'(.

Bug visible in: Edge and Chrome, and also visible in firefox if you apply: transform:rotate(90deg), to the absolute element.

## UPDATE

Ive created a codepen with the pie chart to show more specifically what I'm trying solve:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evXJPw

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "ugly" and "odd". Even if you have to create it in a program like Paint, include a description of your expected results. The fiddle shows a white circle with a thin blue border but without knowing what you expect, it's hard to propose a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove background:blue; from your outer container.
Or if you really want that background color there. Make sure the positioning is dead on then use a 1px border to hide the background gap. Looking good in FF here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpLqPd

Alternatively use SVG, much better for circles.

```
.outer{
  position:relative; 
  width:500px; 
  height:500px; 
  background:blue; 
  border-radius:50%;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: ;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  background:#e3e3e3; 
  border-radius:50%;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
.seeInfirefox{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%)rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! 
You found a solution to the question that i asked for. 
Unfortunately Ive been having some trouble implementing it on my code,
and I'm not sure if the solution will work for my scenario.  
Ive created a codepen with my pie chart, it contains 3 CSS classes 
relevant to the chart. I don't want to bother you with question but if
you have some time to take a look, maybe find a solution it would be amazing!

Pie chart: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evXJPw

Comment: Here you go. Just hide the border bug with another circle element. Very hacky, but it gets the job done. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZePyyJ - SVG is way better for this sort of thing. Here's a good article on how you can do it SVG style https://hackernoon.com/a-simple-pie-chart-in-svg-dbdd653b6936

Comment: WOW, thank you so much! My hero :D! I might look into building an SVG solution in the future but this is great for now, thank you!